# OpenGL glutWireCube works but glutWireCylinder doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

OpenGL `glutWireCube` works but `glutWireCylinder` doesn't.

`glutWireCylinder` throws an `'undefined'` error. How can this be?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to this thread glutWireCylinder does not exist, but glu has a cylinder: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163726-glutSolidCylinder.

Answer (score 0):

That function is not defined because GLUT does not have a function named `glutWireCylinder()`. This is based on the official GLUT documentation here:

https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html

If you don't mind using legacy features, the GLU (GL Utility) library has a function for drawing cylinders (see [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluCylinder.xml) for details).

```
// setup
GLUquadric* quadric = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadric, GLU_LINE);

// drawing
gluCylinder(radius, radius, height, 32, 8);

// cleanup
gluDeleteQuadrc(quadric);
```

If you don't want to use deprecated libraries, writing code to draw a cylinder is easy to write yourself. My answer here shows how to draw a circle, which gets you most of the way to drawing a cylinder: [How to draw a circle using VBO in ES2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279009/how-to-draw-a-circle-using-vbo-in-es2-0).