# How to draw only 1/4 of a circle in OpenGL C++

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw only a sector/part of a circle, but currently I always get a full circle.

I use this to draw a circle:

```
glColor3f (0.25, 1.0, 0.25);
GLfloat angle, raioX=0.3f, raioY=0.3f;
GLfloat circle_points = 100.0f;

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for (int i = 0; i < circle_points; i++) {
    angle = 2*PI*i/circle_points;
    glVertex2f(0.5+cos(angle)*raioX, 0.5+sin(angle)*raioY);        
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: "but not working" can't we have some more precisions ? what actually happens ?

Comment: yes there is a glEnd() but with this code only draw a circle and the idea is draw 1/4 a circle.

Comment: You currently divide 2*PI = 360° between you points, which gives a complete circle. If you need a quarter of it, then use only 90° = PI/2. Every other fraction of a circle works the same way.

Answer (score 5):

#### Assuming you want a sector as illustrated in the [following diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Terminology):

[image]

#### You will need to re-write your code this way:

```
    glBegin    (GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f (0.5f, 0.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < circle_points; i++) {
        angle = 2*PI*i/circle_points;
        glVertex2f (0.5+cos(angle)*raioX, 0.5+sin(angle)*raioY);

    }
    glEnd ();
```

The only thing I changed was the addition of the point `0.5,0.5` at the center of your circle. WIthout that point, you wind up drawing a segment instead of a sector.

---

As BDL points out, your original code drew a full circle. Your angle for 1/4 of a circle should be Pi/2 rather than 2*Pi. So at minimum, you would also need to re-write this line:

```
angle = PI * 0.5f * i / circle_points;
```

BDL's answer shows a more efficient approach to this. Though it draws an arc, which may or may not be what you want. Either way, you have enough code now to draw all three things in the diagram above.

Comment: As long as angle runs from 0 to 2*PI, it will always be a full circle with circle_points subidivisions. For all three type (sector, arc, segment) one has to limit the angle.

Comment: @BDL: Oh, you're right, I didn't even notice that. It should be Pi/2 instead of 2*Pi ;)

Answer (score 3):

The code you will see frequently using a `cos()` and `sin()` call for each point is correct, but very inefficient. Those are fairly expensive functions, and it's easy to write the code so that they are only needed once.

The idea is that you obtain each point from the previous point by rotating it by the angle increment. The rotation itself can be performed by a 2x2 transformation matrix. This reduced the calculation of each point to a few additions and multiplications.

The code will then look something like this:

```
// Calculate angle increment from point to point, and its cos/sin.
float angInc = 0.5f * PI / (circle_points - 1.0f);
float cosInc = cos(angInc);
float sinInc = sin(angInc);

// Start with vector (1.0f, 0.0f), ...
float xc = 1.0f;
float yc = 0.0f;

// ... and then rotate it by angInc for each point.
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
for (int i = 0; i < circle_points; i++) {
    glVertex2f(0.5f + xc, 0.5f + yc);        
    float xcNew = cosInc * xc - sinInc * yc;
    yc = sinInc * xc + cosInc * yc;
    xc = xcNew;
}
glEnd();
```

As a subtle detail, note that if you want to draw a quarter circle with `circle_points` points, including the start and end point, you need to divide the angle range by `circle_points - 1` to obtain the angle increment. It's the thing with the number of fence posts and number of gaps between them...

This will draw a circle segment. Andon already elaborated on the difference between a segment and a sector.

The above shared code with my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25321141/3530129, which shows how to draw a circle with modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

When drawing a fraction of a circle, one needs to limit the angle in which the points should be placed. circle_points defines then in how many subparts this circle arc should be devided. In addition (and as pointed out by @Andon M. Coleman) using a GL_LINE_LOOP might not be the correct choice, since it will always close the line from the last to the first point.

You're code could be modified somehow like this:

```
glColor3f (0.25, 1.0, 0.25);
GLfloat angle, raioX=0.3f, raioY=0.3f;
GLfloat circle_points = 100;
GLfloat circle_angle = PI / 2.0f;

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int i = 0; i <= circle_points; i++) {
    GLfloat current_angle = circle_angle*i/circle_points;
    glVertex2f(0.5+cos(current_angle)*raioX, 0.5+sin(current_angle)*raioY);        
}
glEnd();
```